# Default TaskExecutor implementation for Async event listeners

Tags: spring, spring-boot, executorservice

I am using an annotation-based event listener which I have also tagged as `@Async`. (See [Asynchronous Listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events-async)).

Which `TaskExecutor` implementation is Spring using to serve these requests? [The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-qualification) reads:

> By default, when specifying @Async on a method, the executor that is used is the one configured when enabling async support, i.e. the “annotation-driven” element if you are using XML or your AsyncConfigurer implementation, if any.

The problem is that I haven't done *any* configuration for this at all, so I am not sure what my `AsyncConfigurer` implementation is to begin with.

My *guess* is that we're dealing a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) for `EnableAsync`:

> By default, Spring will be searching for an associated thread pool definition: either a unique TaskExecutor bean in the context, or an Executor bean named "taskExecutor" otherwise. If neither of the two is resolvable, a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor will be used to process async method invocations.

So, it's the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.